# ContentByQueryWebPart and numeric field display as integer

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a site column:

```
<Field ID="{4BB20187-638A-47A6-96EF-FFE1CA5A9A2C}"
     Name="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
     CanToggleHidden="TRUE"
     StaticName="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
     DisplayName="Nombre de places demandées"
     Type="Number"
     Decimals="0"
     Required="TRUE"
     />
```

This site column is bound in a custom content type:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100C74070DC6A24431BAFDA7E34EB40AB71"
           Name="Participation générique"             
           Description="Élément de formulaire générique"
           Inherits="FALSE"
           Overwrite="TRUE"
           Version="0">
<FieldRefs>

  <FieldRef ID="{4BB20187-638A-47A6-96EF-FFE1CA5A9A2C}"
            Name="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
            DisplayName="Nombre de places demandées" />

</FieldRefs>
```

I also have defined a custom list schema dedicated to this content type:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint"
      Title="Liste générique"
      FolderCreation="FALSE"
      DisableAttachments="TRUE"
      Direction="$Resources:core,Direction;"
      Url="Lists/Liste générique"
      BaseType="0"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
      EnableContentTypes="TRUE">
    <MetaData>
        <ContentTypes>
            <ContentType ID="0x0100C74070DC6A24431BAFDA7E34EB40AB71"
               Name="Participation générique"             
               Description="Élément de formulaire générique"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Overwrite="TRUE"
               Version="0">
                <FieldRefs>

                    <FieldRef ID="{4BB20187-638A-47A6-96EF-FFE1CA5A9A2C}"
                Name="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
                DisplayName="Nombre de places demandées" />

                </FieldRefs>
            </ContentType>
        </ContentTypes>
        <Fields>
            <!--
      Other fields truncated  
     -->

            <Field ID="{4BB20187-638A-47A6-96EF-FFE1CA5A9A2C}"
             Name="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
             CanToggleHidden="TRUE"
             StaticName="NumberOfPlacesRequested"
             DisplayName="Nombre de places demandées"
             Type="ParticipationField"
             Decimals="0"
             Required="TRUE"
             Group="xyz" />

        </Fields>
        <Views>
            <!--
            truncated 
          -->
        </Views>
        <Forms>
            <!--
            truncated 
          -->
        </Forms>
    </MetaData>
</List>
```

Everything is working fine with the list itself. However, I have troubles using the ContentByQueryWebPart.

1. If I setup the content by query webpart to target directly a list based on this template, the column renders as expected:

[image: expected render]

2. However, if I setup the content by query web part to show all date of the current site, and select the list template type (`Liste générique)`, the CQWP renders with decimals:

[image: unexpected render]

Here is the excerpt of my xsl file that renders the value:

```
    <span>
      <xsl:value-of select="@NumberOfPlacesRequested" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#x26;nbsp;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@NumberOfPlacesRequested = 1">invitation demandée</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>invitations demandées</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </span>
```

**How can I ensure that my value will always be displayed as integer, with no decimal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be as follows:

```
<span>
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@NumberOfPlacesRequested, '0')" />
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#x26;nbsp;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@NumberOfPlacesRequested = 1">invitation demandée</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>invitations demandées</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</span>
```

[MSDN reference: format-number function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Also, in case `@NumberOfPlacesRequested` is a string (it can easily be so, because internally SharePoint stores numbers as strings anyway ;) ), then perhaps you will need to wrap it in [number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256211.aspx)() as well, i.e. like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(@NumberOfPlacesRequested), '0')"/>
```

Comment: With no surprise, this solved the issue. However, I still feel this is only hiding SharePoint mess. I don't like not understanding what I do. But this is the daily pain with SP, isn't it ?:)

Comment: SharePoint is so huge a monster, and has so many bugs that learning how it works may take just too much time. So while I agree that understanding is important, but I think there should be some limit of how deep you can dive into SP guts :) And BTW it could even be not a SharePoint bug, but XSLT bug. I found some mentions in internet that sometimes XSLT outputs numbers incorrectly.